# Regexp for css font declaration

Tags: javascript, css, regex

This is a font declaration in css:

```
font: bold italic small-caps 1em/1.5em verdana,sans-serif;
```

This is a regexp that is working to get the value in px:

```
value.match(/(normal|italic)?\s*(normal|small-caps)?\s*(normal|bold|bolder|lighter|100|200|300|400|500|600|700|800|900)?\s*(\d+)px(?:\/(normal|[\d\.]+))?\s+(.*)/);
```

And helps me getting this:

```
  var fontStyle = match[1],
       // font variant is not used
       // fontVariant = match[2],
       fontWeight = match[3],
       fontSize = match[4],
       lineHeight = match[5],
       fontFamily = match[6];
```

I would like to parse any value for font size or  lineheight non just px, but

```
[px|cm|mm|em|pt|pc|in]
```

But i'm not able to modify it.
Can someone help?

Final result:

```
(normal|italic)?\s*(normal|small-caps)?\s*(normal|bold|bolder|lighter|100|200|30‌​0|400|500|600|700|800|900)?\s*(\d+(?:px|cm|mm|em|pt|pc|in)*)(?:\/(normal|[\d\.]+)‌​)?\s+(.*)
```

Comment: What about [`vh`, `vw`, `vmin` and `vmax`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)?

Comment: ok googling them.... back in 5 minutes.

Comment: For now i pretend that vw vh and rem does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `px`  in your regex with:

```
(\d+(?:px|cm|mm|em|pt|pc|in|%))
```

Note the parenthesis.

**Update:** The value is also captured now.

Comment: I tried to do that, but it recognize the measure unit as an additiona match. I want it to match 6px or 5in as a single match, not two separate.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this was what best suited me.
The other where producing more results, and the one that i did by myself (\d+em|\d+px|\d+cm|\d+) .... was so ugly.
Thanks even for the vw vh and % units, but i'm discarding them

I added an asterisk after the parentesis to accept even without measure unit.

(normal|italic)?\s*(normal|small-caps)?\s*(normal|bold|bolder|lighter|100|200|300|400|500|600|700|800|900)?\s*(\d+(?:px|cm|mm|em|pt|pc|in)*)(?:\/(normal|[\d\.]+))?\s+(.*)

Comment: So the roundy brakets are both for capturing in match and for logical grouping? and that is why we use that "?:" meaning do not capture?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi: That's right, `(?:...)` means a non capture group.

Answer (score 1):

Do not parse CSS with regexps. Instead, let the engine do it--it already knows how to, perfectly!!

```js
var elt = document.createElement('div');
elt.style.font = '1em sans-serif';
// individual properties can now be accessed as elt.style.fontFamily etc.

['fontFamily', 'fontSize'].forEach(function(x) { 
    document.writeln(x, " is ", elt.style[x], ". "); });
```

However, for this to work, the format of the `font` specification must be correct (in the correct order). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, i'm gonna propose it, but if possible i'm skipping bothering the document that in my case is an SVG and it doesn't have all the properties i need or it doesn't have across all browsers. ( nodejs, oldIE... i'm not so expert, changing would mean test everything from scratch )